# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('NISPUF17.csv')
cleaned = df[['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']]
(cleaned[cleaned['CBF_01']==1]) & (cleaned[cleaned['CBF_01']==2])
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

```
cleaned[(cleaned['CBF_01']==1) & (cleaned['CBF_01']==2)]
```

This will give you desired rows from 'cleaned' Dataframe